# I want to change the value of the template of directive

Tags: angularjs

I define a directive like this:

```
module.directive("jump", function(html){
var text = html.getHtml();
return{
    scope:{},
    restrict:"AE",
    template: text,
}
});
```

And I have a service to store the html, like this:

```
module.factory('html',function(){
var html = "";
return {
    setHtml: function(text){
        html = text;
    },
    getHtml: function(){
        return html;
    }
}
})
```

I want to change the template value when I enter article page，because the detail of every article are different, and I only can get it from API, it's like

```
<p><a href="#" ng-click="open(\'http://www.facebook.com\')"facebook</a></p>
```

I want to define a directive for every article to show the detail of article.
But now, when I enter one article page, the directive's template is defined, and if I want to see other article, the template value is the first article's detail.I want to know how to change it.

Answer (score 0):

#### "Note: All services in Angular are singletons."

- (src: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers)

If you need to have the html be different for each instance of your directive, you can't use a singleton that restricts it to a single instance.

Why not just define the template from within the directive? It's a much cleaner pattern that way. Something like this:

directive in use:

```
<div ng-repeat="foo in dataFromApiThatYouGetFirst">
  <jump url="{{foo.url}}" title="{{foo.title}}"></jump>
</div>
```

directive:

```
restrict: 'E',
template: '<p><a href="#" ng-click="open(vm.url)">{{vm.title}}</a></p>',
replace: true,
scope: {
  url: '=?',
  title: '=?'
},
controllerAs: 'vm',
bindToController: true,
```

Comment: Thanks for your help,But because for each instance,there are many ng-click, and I do not know how much ng-click until I got it from the API.So, I think this way cannot solve my problem.Is there has any other method?

Comment: run your api GET call first, bind the data you get back from the api to the scope, and build your dom dynamically from the model. Thinking about it in terms of dom elements first doesn't make any sense. I edited my response to show how you can use a custom directive inside of an ng-repeat directive instance

Comment: No,this method also cannot solve my problem.Because each instance data is a string data type which contains a lot of html tags，such as “<p ng-click="open()">xxx</p><img ng-click="open()"/><iframe></iframe>”And every instance data is different.If use your method, I can solve the ng-click, but I cannot to show them in the browser correct